# IIS Windows Web Application Returning 403 Error

Tags: web, iis, server

I have an issue with my IIS web application where a user trying to connect from a different computer is getting a 403 error.

I have tried adding `<sessionState mode="Off" />` to my `web.config`, but this has not helped.

Comment: Read IIS log files to learn the substatus code, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: Thank you for your help.
403 0 0 124

Comment: 403.0 is strange. Run FRT to see what gives you that 403.0, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Do you faced the 403.0  Not Allowed error ? The error message is "You do not have permission to view this directory or page.". Could you please post the details information about your web application and your IIS default document setting?

Comment: here is the error i did F12 on chrome /front-office/api/MarquesModeles/List
Authorization has been denied for this request.

it's look like it's only allowing 1 user per connection how to allow multiple connection

Comment: I'm not sure but it's like
asp net or maybe another module creation 1 pipeline for all users from same IP.
i have tried to use from different TAB on CHROME and i'm getting 403 for 2nd user.